# Advantages of using HttpSocket over curl or file_get_contents?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? I ask so that i may make better use of the tools. Also, does HttpSocket fallback to using different ways to communicate if, for instance Curl is not available on the server?

Comment: when down voting, please state the reason so that all that come across the same question can gain value from your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do any kind of a request outside of a GET you will have a hard time using `file_get_contents()`. HttpSocket won't have any restrictions around HTTP methods or the types of data it can send. file_get_contents() can also be hampered by the `allow_fopen_url` configuration value being disabled. HttpSocket doesn't have these same issues.

As long as `allow_fopen_url` is true you could use the stream functions to make file_get_contents() do most anything, but it isn't nearly as simple as using HttpSocket in my opinion.